# ExtJs Property Grid Custom Editor - updating value from dialog window combobox

Tags: extjs

I am trying to create a property grid custom editor that shows a dialogue and allows a user to select a new value for the field.

I cannot get the value selected from the combobox in the dialogue window to update in the custom editor in the property grid, and cannot understand why. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myObject = { 
        number: 'One'
    };

    // custom editor
    Ext.define('Ext.form.DialogEditorField', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
        alias: 'widget.dialogEditorField',
        editable: true,
        onTriggerClick: function() {
            var me = this;
            if(!me.dialog) {
                alert('Dialog property not set');
                return;
            }
            if(me.disabled) return;
            if(me.dialog.loadValue) me.dialog.loadValue(this);
            me.dialog.on('hide', function() {
                me.setValue('Five');
            });
            me.dialog.show();
        }
    });

    // dialog to show
    var myDialog = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Example Dialog',
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closable: true,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        bbar: [
            '->',
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Save',
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                        scope: this,
                        fn: function() {
                            var combo = Ext.getCmp('numberCombo');
                            myDialog.saveValue(combo.getValue());
                            myDialog.hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Cancel',
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                        fn: function() {
                        myDialog.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                id: 'numberCombo',
                editable: false,
                fieldLabel: 'Number',
                store: [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'],
                queryMode: 'local'
            })
        ],
        loadValue: function(field) {
            this.fieldId = field.id;
            var combo = Ext.getCmp('numberCombo');
            combo.setValue(field.getValue());
        },
        saveValue: function(value) {
            var field = Ext.getCmp(this.fieldId);
            field.setValue(value);
        }
    });

    // propert grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
        title: 'Properties Grid',
        width: 300,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        source: myObject,
        sourceConfig: {
            number: {
                displayName: 'Number',
                editor: Ext.create('widget.dialogEditorField', {
                    dialog: myDialog
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a DOM navigation issue meaning I was pointing to the field when I should have been setting the value of the custom editor.

Answered by chramer from Sencha forums - I just needed to change the following code:

```
saveValue: function(value) {
    var field = Ext.getCmp(this.fieldId);
    field.setValue(value);
}
```

To:

```
saveValue: function (value) {
    field = Ext.getCmp(this.fieldId);
    grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].set('value', value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following sample. I tried another way. The reason is that your code is so mixed. For instance, do you need a dialog window to change a specific record?

[Grid Panel - Cell Edit](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/44d)

Comment: The code example is just a basic demonstration of the requirement, and will eventually become a more complex piece of code; satisfying the requirement for using the dialog box will simplify aspects of the requirement later. Also, the question centres more on why the combobox in the dialog box does not update the custom editor to show the selected value, rather the choice of ExtJS component.